# while extracting double type field from Oracle DB automatically appends .0 to the value

Tags: java, database, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I am using JPA to incorporate Oracle DB in spring boot. I have an entity in which a field is defined as below:

```
 @Column(name = "TOTAL_PREMIUM", precision = 12, scale = 2)
private double totalPremium = 0;
```

In the DB the stored value I can see is like this[image]:

But when i am trying to get this value using JPARepository:

```
Quotes quotes = quoteRepo.findOne(quoteID);
quotes.getTotalPremium()
```

It gives **2.0, 1348.0** like this, Its kind of mismatch for me.

IS there any way i can get whatever is saved i.e. value should be 2, 1348

If it is saved with some decimal value like 1389.48 then it should return me 1389.48, if I save 1389 then it should return  1389.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you store the value into Double variable then 2.0 = 2 = 2.000 ;) So no problems there

Comment: @VeselinDavidov yes you are right. But there is the case of matching the exact value like i am getting value without decimal from third party. and then there is the enquiry on the saved data if it is same or not

Comment: Well if you receive the value without a decimal then... parse it as an integer because it's not a double at this point.

Comment: why downvote, this is my genuine problem and i have described it well, if any corrections i have to do please let me know

Comment: Then you need to map it to String and compare it as a string afterwards. If you map it to double you should treat it as double

Comment: @Ben it is already integer in this case why i have to parse it.

Comment: "It gives 2.0" is completely wrong - someone has decided to show that particular with one decimal digit. Its entirely up to you if you want to display as `2` , `2.0` or  `2.0000000000000000`

Comment: Yeah and it's all the same. Compare number values like numbers and string values like strings. If you have a double here compare it as a number and don't care about zeroes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column is mapped to a double type:

```
@Column(name = "TOTAL_PREMIUM", precision = 12, scale = 2)
private double totalPremium = 0;
```

Here you lose any numbers of tailing zeroes written in the database because if the database have 2.000 or 2.0 or 2 in the Java code you will get the same double value 2.

So if you need to compare it to a String later on you need to map that totalPremium to a String in your Entity and compare strings. Or parse the double value from the String you compare to and compare the two double values. I think you should do the latter because if you compare numbers you should compare them the mathematical way.

Comment: In my case i am not loosing trailing zeroes, actually value is appended with .0 when i am trying to get it but saved value as you can see in the image is without .0, could you elaborate this

Comment: What do you mean you get it? Your totalPremium value is a double value. It is 2 ( or 2.0 which is the same). Where do you see it 2.0? Do you make it a string or something?

Comment: please check my updated question i am trying to get like this quotes.getTotalPremium()